# Randomly color each word of mail body using Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using this `javascript` to randomly color each word of mail body.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink','black'];
$('blockquote').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().split(' ').map(function(v){
        return '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]+'">'+v+'</span>';
    }).join(' '));
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

But, it doesn't working in actual mail body. But, source code of received mail exactly working when I'm running it through `html` file.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Mail clients have their ways to display HTML (to some extent even with CSS) but you should not mistake them for browsers of any sort. As far as I remember most clients lack a decent JS engine inside, heck, even the images taken from external sources have a hard time.

A possible solution would be compiling whatever you are trying to send via a task runner (Grunt/Gulp) or having the final document prepared otherwise and send the output HTML.

Comment: Exactly, you would want to use plain HTML in an e-mail

Comment: what's your exact suggestion ? Since, I tried the last one. `send the output in HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your code for reading. You should use map function correctly.

```js
    $(window).load(function() {
      var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'black'];
      $('blockquote').each(function() {
        var array = $(this).text().split(' ');
        var newArray = $.map(array, function(v) {
          return '<span style="color:' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] + '">' + v + '</span>';
        });
        $(this).html(newArray.join(' '));
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>11111 11111</blockquote>
<blockquote>11111 11111</blockquote>
<blockquote>1111 111111</blockquote>
<blockquote>11111 11111</blockquote>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a var to store your new html :

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'black'];
$('blockquote').each(function () {
    var newText = "";
    $(this).html($(this).text().split(' ').map(function (v) {
        newText += encodeURIComponent('<span style="color:' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] + '">' + v + '</span> ');
    }));
    $(this).html(newText);
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/x5a9anez/3/

Comment: @jWeaver I've just updated my answer and added `encodeURIComponent` for the html. Can you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the fact that you're trying to run JavaScript in an email message is the source of your problem, but this [list of CSS support in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) might be helpful in any event.